# How to handle Options in orientdb blueprint

Tags: scala, orientdb, tinkerpop-blueprint

I'm using Scala and OrientDB with Blueprint API.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-core" % "2.1.16"
libraryDependencies += "com.tinkerpop.blueprints" % "blueprints-core" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-graphdb" % "2.1.16"
libraryDependencies += "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-client" % "2.1.16"
libraryDependencies += "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-enterprise" % "2.1.16"
```

The behavior when i'm going to store a val of type Option[Int](to an integer type) is this:

```
val vertex: Vertex = graph.addVertex("prova",null)
vertex.setProperty("foo",None) //It store an empty value
```

This behavior is correct, but if i'm going to store an Option[String] (to a String type) i get this:

```
val a: Option[String] = None
val vertex: Vertex = graph.addVertex("prova",null)
vertex.setProperty("foo",a) //It store "None" instead of empty, why?
```

How can avoid this?

**SOLVED**

I've added this to configuration

```
new OrientGraphFactory().setStandardElementConstraints(false)
```

And i changed the code like this:

```
val a: Option[String] = None //or Some("foo")
val vertex: Vertex = graph.addVertex("prova",null)
vertex.setProperty("foo",a.orNull)
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, which version of orient libraries are you using ?

Comment: Hi Alessandro. I've found the solution. Grazie lo stesso ;-)